# How to get command not found response in scripting in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I am starting with scripting in ubuntu. Its very easy and good thing to do. In my shell scripting, I need to run few linux command to change directory, or to remove files or copy files or any other command. So I was just wondering is this possible to get the command not found notification in scripting so that if any command fails at any time, we can show error message on terminal to user.

I searched a little about this on google and found out that using below we can read the terminal response:

```
fooVar=$(ls)
echo "Response: $fooVar"
```

So above I am running `ls` command so on terminal it looks like something:

```
Response:
folder1
folder2
file1
file2
```

But if I do something like

```
fooVar=$(lsv)
echo "Response: $fooVar"
```

It gives me error `lsv command not found` which is ok because `lsv` is not a command but this string should come like this

```
Response: lsv command not found
```

Is this possible or I am going into wrong way. Also how can we put an if condition for this error. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error,

> lsv command not found

is send to `stderror` whereas normal output are sendt to `stdout`. You will have to redirect `stderror` to `stdout`:

```
$ fooVar=$(lsv 2>&1)
$ echo "Response: $fooVar"
Response: -bash: lsv: command not found
```

This is almost what you want, execpt for the `-bash:`

Stdout has filedescriptor 1 and stderr has descriptor 2. So what i says is 'send stderr to the same place as stdout'. You could use somthing similar to put output or errors to files:

```
ls > outfile 2> errorfile
```

Will put the normal output in a file called 'outfile', and eventual errors in 'errfile'.

```
ls >> outfile 2>> errorfile
```

Will append to the files instead of resetting them. And you can use only the one or the other redirect.

Comment: Thank You for telling me about `stderror`. I will study more on it. Can you please explain what does `2>&1` means in your first line. Also how can we put if statement for this condition

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
fooVar="lsv"
echo -n "Response "; echo `$fooVar`
```

Comment: You almost failed to make it wrong ;-) THe variable, fooVar, doesn't contain the error message, when the command is wrong, and the output isn't displayed correctly when the command is correct.

Comment: what does `-n` with echo indicates

Comment: -n is 'no newline' ..